# GarageBand not opening on MacBook Pro

Tags: garageband

When I try to open GarageBand it comes up with the error message 'GarageBand quit unexpectedly' as pictured. [image: ]]

When I try to reopen it it bounces around for a bit and then comes up with this message again. 
I have tried re-installing and deleting preferences, neither of which worked. I am using a MacBook Pro, 10.10.5
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you clear the saved state at `~/Library/Saved Application State/` ?

Comment: There is no save state in ~/Library/Saved Application State/

Comment: :/ then can you post the entire text of the crash report, rather than a picture of it - see if someone can get a hint as to what's failing. Pro Tip: Edit your question & paste the text - then select all the report text  & hit Ctrl/K which will format it as code. *Ctrl, not Cmd.*

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious and standard computer practice, but restarting my computer worked - the most simple and easy solution that the Internet never recommends or even mentions.